# Java With (Object) Statement

Tags: java, android

```
public int alertBox (String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDialogBuilder
        .setTitle(title) <------ ????
        .setMessage(text)  <--------- ?????
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();

    return 1;
}
```

As far as I have read, Java does not have a Visual Basic-like "With object --- .property = xyz" statement. i.e.

```
With x
  .caption = "caption"
 ...
```

Can someone explain what is going on above that the alertDialogBuilder in Android seems to have an implied object capability?

Does this apply to anything else in Java?  In Android?  How does one know when this can be used.  Is this an Android Java thing?  Can you make methods and functions that employ this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alertDialogBuilder
        .setTitle(title) <------ ????
        .setMessage(text)
```

That is [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) in java and called as Builder pattern, where each method on that instance returns on it self.

Writing it in simple lines to understand

```
alertDialogBuilder = alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
 alertDialogBuilder =alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(text);
 ---
```

Comment: So some classes employ this and some do not?  It depends on the class then, correct?

Comment: Exactly. It really depends.

Comment: I tried it on a couple of other classes and it didn't work, so that explains it!

Comment: @B.Nadolson yes, if the class implement/followed the builder patter (which returns instance for it's method), you can able to do that. Otherwise no.

Comment: @B.Nadolson Or you can simply call when ever you are returning an instance from that method call, you can invoke method of that instance.

Answer (score 1):

What's going on is a usage of the [Builder Pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html). The set methods set the value and return the builder object, allowing you to chain calls.

When the builder is 'done', you call the `create` method on it to return the actual needed object.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for this *specific* class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

It employs the Builder Design Pattern, so that every method returns the updated object to enable chaining. For example, look at `setTitle`:

> public AlertDialog.Builder setTitle (CharSequence title)
>
> Set the title displayed in the Dialog.
>
> **Returns**
> This Builder object to allow for chaining of calls to set methods

You can see both in description and as the return type that it enables chaining on purpose. Again, this is specific for this class in Android and is not true in general, let alone for Java.

Answer (score 0):

The lines you have marked with `<------ ????` are continuations of the previous line. You can tell by the lack of `;`.

The methods `setTitle`, `setMessage` etc... are returning an object instance (`AlertDialog.Builder`) on which you can call the next method. The returned object is actually the same as the one on which you call the method. This is called the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Basically, each of these methods ends with `return this;`.

An alternative would be:

```
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(text);
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
...
```

Comment: I noticed the lack of a semi-colon.  Then I noticed other classes didn't acknowledge doing this either.